# Emgu Camera Calibration

Tags: c#, opencv, camera-calibration, emgucv

I am using emgu/opencv to find the position of some flat blobs. I can currently find their positions in pixels and would like to convert this to world coordinates (in/mm). I have looked at emgu's camera calibration [example](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php?title=Camera_Calibration), but I am having trouble actually applying it to get what I want. Using the example, I believe I can get the intrinsic matrix, but I am not really sure what to do with it. My camera is fixed and is looking down at the fixed plane the blobs are on. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have to shot another image from another viewpoint. You cannot get the world coordinates with only one image.  [Read this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Stereo_Imaging)

Comment: If the calibration grid is placed in a known location in the world and the grid is of a known size, shouldn't I be able to figure out world coordinates with one camera after it has been calibrated?

Comment: I know the size and location of the calibration grid was known,  otherwise you coundnot get the intrisic paramters.    The calibration grid only affect the calibration process, and will determine the accuracy of your intrisic parameters. However, you still need at least two images from two different viewpoints, and the extrinsic parameters between these two viewpoints ( rotation matrix and translation vector).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a little like you just want to know the size of flat objects that are located on the same plane as a calibration pattern. If that´s the case this is quite easy if the camera is looking normal onto the plane (no perspective distortion). You can then just calculate a pixel to millimeter conversion factor from the calibration pattern and you are done.

If that´s not the case and you want to fully calibrate your camera, you can either move your camera or if you only have one image use a 3D- calibration pattern. This is to avoid that all points are coplanar which leads to a degenerated solution.